# Phase I Method of Log Barrier Optimization, LP

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, quadratic-programming

In Dr. Boyd's Convex Optimization homework problems, there is a method described for a so-called Phase I method, which is used to determine a feasible starting point for an LP, to be used later in a log-barrier optimization method. It described here, pg. 3,

https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364a/hw8extra.pdf

It basically says in order to obtain a feasible starting point for an LP solve this problem,

$$
\min t, \quad \textrm{s.t.}
$$
$$
Ax = b, \quad x \ge (1-t) \vec{1}, \quad t \ge 0
$$

where $t$ is scalar. This problem is also solved with the barrier method, which also requires a starting point but that is simpler, we take $x^0$ of $Ax^0 = b$, and take $t^0 = 2 - \min_i x_i^0$.

But the rest of the steps are less clear: I dont understand is how the intermediate variable $z$ is used, which we are told, is computed as

$$
z = x + (t-1)\vec{1}
$$

I have seen numerical coding of this method, they do things like

```
A1 = [A,-A*ones(n,1)];
b1 = b-A*ones(n,1);
z0 = x0+t0*ones(n,1)-ones(n,1);
c1 = [zeros(n,1);1];
[z_star, history, gap] = lp_barrier(A1,b1,c1,[z0;t0]);
```

I guess $c$ is made into $c = [0, 0, 0, ..., 1]$ where they multiply existing $x_i$'s with zero, only the extra $x_{i+1}$ remains which can be seen as $t$. Not as clear about what is going on with $A_1$ though. A new column is added to $A$ which is the negative of the sum of each of its rows. One derivation I could come up with

$$
z = x + t \vec{1} - \vec{1}
$$

$$
x = z - t\vec{1} + \vec{1}
$$

Apply to $Ax = b$ ,

$$
A (z - t\vec{1} + \vec{1}) = b
$$

$$
Az - A t\vec{1} = b - A\vec{1}
$$

The $b_1$ calculation make sense with this, but is $Az - A t\vec{1}$ equivalent to expanding $A$ with negative sum of its existing rows and adding $t$ as a new dummy variable?

Thanks,

Note: the code for `lp_barrier` comes from a HW [solution](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364a/hw8sol.pdf), page 7.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that looks correct.  Note that $A t\vec{1}=A \vec{1} t$ because $t$ is a scalar.  Also, the introduction of $z$ transforms the $x \ge (1-t) \vec{1}$ constraint into a lower bound of $0$ for $z$, which apparently is a requirement for `lp_barrier`.

Comment: Yes `lp_barrier` expects standard form LP, constraints has to be in the form of $Ax=b$ and $x \ge 0$.

Comment: About the extra column in $A$ though, I don't get it, maybe it's a stupid mistake, but is it equivalent to expand $A$ in this way (adding $A\vec{1}$ as a new column, and make $t$ a new cell in $x$) to  $Az - A\vec{1}t$?

Comment: Yes, columns in the constraint matrix are in one-to-one correspondence with the decision variables.